# Percentage circle border CSS React

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I try to create a circle with a border in which I can control the ratio of the red part to the green part. I am using React and styled-components. I created something like this:

```
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";

const Wrapper = styled.div`
  margin: 50px auto;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background: ${({ theme }) => theme.red};
  border-radius: 50%;
`;

const Circle = styled.div``;

const MaskFull = styled.div`
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  clip: rect(0px, 150px, 150px, 75px);
  animation: fill ease-in-out 3s;
  transform: rotate(126deg);
`;

const Fill = styled.div`
  clip: rect(0px, 75px, 150px, 0px);
  background-color: ${({ theme }) => theme.green};
  animation: fill ease-in-out 3s;
  transform: rotate(126deg);
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
`;

const InsideCircle = styled.div`
  width: 130px;
  height: 130px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #fff;
  line-height: 130px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 100;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 2em;
`;

const SecondMask = styled.div`
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  clip: rect(0px, 150px, 150px, 75px);
`;

const Avatar: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <Wrapper>
      <Circle>
        <MaskFull>
          <Fill />
        </MaskFull>
        <SecondMask>
          <Fill />
        </SecondMask>
        <InsideCircle />
      </Circle>
    </Wrapper>
  );
};

export default Avatar;
```

but as you can see on the picture, there is an ugly 1px protruding red fragment. I can't find the bug in my code, how can I fix it?

[image]

Comment: I think the main issue is here the border-radius property. Try to adjust all 4 values: border-radius: topleft, topright, bottomright, bottomleft to achieve the overlap of the visible circle overflow. Or other solution you can create an outher white mask div with a hole to fit the circle into it.

Comment: Frankly use an SVG, much simpler all round

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is don't think it's particularly a bug in your code - it's just that the system is trying to work out how to show part CSS pixels on a screen which uses several screen pixels per CSS pixel. Some can get 'left behind'.

A different way of creating the effect you want is to use background images made up of a conic gradient overlaid with a radial one (to give the 'hole' in the middle).

This is a simple snippet to demonstrate the idea in HTML/CSS. The CSS variable --ratio could be set in JS using setProperty to whatever the ratio of red to green is required.

```css
.ratio {
  --ratio: 0.3;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
  clip-path: circle(50%);
}

.ratio::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-image: conic-gradient(red 0 calc(var(--ratio) * 360deg), lime calc(var(--ratio) * 360deg) 360deg);
  z-index: -2;
}

.ratio::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 80%;
  height: 80%;
  top: 10%;
  left: 10%;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="ratio"></div>
```

Note: while it is possible to get the same effect using a simpler set up - just one background-image statement on the actual div with first the radial gradient and then the conic gradient you can run into another 'pixel' problem, a sort of fuzziness around the curves. Hence this snippet tidies the circles up with clip-path to give smooth edges.